# Fade In/Out text and Loop using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

My html template has the following div:

```
<div dojoAttachPoint="container" class="container">
        <span dojoAttachPoint="searchingForMore" id="searchingForMore" class="searchingForMore"></span>
    </div>
```

I also have a function that does the fade in and out of my two texts once.

```
_alternateSearchingProvText: function () {
    var node = dom.byId("searchingForMore");
    node.innerHTML = "first text";
    fx.fadeOut({
        node: node,
        duration: 60000,
        onEnd: function() {
            node.innerHTML = "Second text";
            dojo.fadeIn({
                node: node
            }).play()
        }
    }).play();
```

I want to do this periodically in a loop until the view is dismissed from the screen. How do I achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by view dissmissed ?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @bRIMOs when the dialog is "destroyed" so to speak

Comment: So basically you need to trigger `fadeIn` when `fadeOut` ends and trigger `fadeOut` when `fadeIn` ends. To achieve this, just create handlers of both animations. Initially `fadeOutHandler` plays. In it's `onEnd` do `fadeInHandler.play()`. In `fadeInHandler`'s `onEnd` do `fadeOutHandler.play()`. This will create a loop of animations.

Comment: @Himanshu Okay - Thank you! I think I have figured this out based on what you explained to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this simply by using the `setInterval` js funcion , wich trigger the annimation every specified time (in milli seconds),

So if you annimation duration is `3s` so the timeout for the interval should be `2 times` the animation dration

You can see bellow working snippet  in which I've used the setInterval , and stopped this last once dialog closed (using `clearInterval`).

```js
require(["dijit/Dialog","dojo/_base/fx","dijit/registry","dojo/dom","dojo/ready","dijit/form/Button"],
 function(Dialog,fx,registry,dom,ready,Button){
    var interval;
    var duration = 4000;
    var text = "First text";
    var node;
    
   ready(function(){
      registry.byId("btn").on("click",function(e){
          followUpDialog.show();
          annimation();
      });
      
      var dialogContent = ' <span dojoAttachPoint="searchingForMore" id="searchingForMore" class="searchingForMore"></span>';
      
      
      
      // instantiate new custom dialog
      var followUpDialog = new Dialog({
        id:'myDialog',
        title: "Create new follow-up",
        content: dialogContent,
        style: "width: 730px",
        onShow: function() {
          node = dom.byId("searchingForMore");
          
          node.innerHTML = text;
          interval = setInterval(function(){
            annimation();
            
          },duration*2)
        },
        onHide: function () {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      });
      
      function annimation() {
        text = text == "First text" ? "Second text" : "First text";
            
        fx.fadeOut({
            node: node,
            duration: duration,
            onEnd: function() {
              node.innerHTML = text;
              fx.fadeIn({
                node: node,
                duration: duration
              }).play();;
            }
        }).play();  
      }
    });
  }
);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojoConfig = {isDebug: true, async: true, parseOnLoad: true}
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="claro">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="btn"> click me </div>
</body>
```